# For loop switch handling

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm curious as to why switches directly following the set command with no spaces, work the same as if there are spaces;

`set /a i+=1`, works the same as `set/a i+=1`, and even `set/ai+=1`

Yet - the same logic does not apply to the for command - the following will not work:

```
for/L %a in (1,1,2) do echo %a
```

However it produces the error:

```
'for' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

instead of what I expected to be `'for/L' is not recognized ...`

My question is why, when it clearly differentiates the switch from the command, does it not accept the syntax, and subsequently not work - furthermore, why does it produce the error seen above?

Comment: M$ built different parsers for `set`, `for`, `for /f`, `if` and `echo`. So you should ask the M$ trainees from last century. You can find more about the strange language on dostips.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most internal commands use a consistent parser, and they generally accept the form `commandName/option`. But the FOR and IF commands are more complex, and have special parsing rules. The fact that `FOR/L ...` and `IF/I ...` do not work is some of the evidence that they actually have their own special parsing rules. jeb has done much study on how the batch parser works, but I've never seen his complete analysis of how FOR and IF work.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that they clearly have special parsing rules - the thing that confuses me though, is that the error returned seems to recognize the separation between command and switch.

Comment: The error seems to come from the shell as opposed to the parser. Which would suggest that it's not to do with the difference in parser. For example, the error returned is the same as if you were to enter `foo` as a command.

Comment: I may just be not understanding some basic principals of parser / shell operations.

Comment: @unclemeat - The shell and the internal commands are one and the same. SET, FOR, IF , ECHO ... and many more are built into the CMD.EXE shell.

Comment: That makes sense. It's still quite strange that the error returned says that `for` is not recognized as opposed to `for/L`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical parsing for the two commands is different: one takes switches, the other doesn't.

Without consulting the programmers that implemented the windows batch script language, we can't say why that is so.

I think it's fair to say though that judging by the quality of the language in general, I wouldn't hold out much hope for a rational answer.

Comment: How is `/A` a switch for SET, while `/L` not a switch for FOR?